# On SharePoint Online, I have a sub-site but want the site Visitors group to be different than the parent

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint Online site, and the Visitors group has one entry "Everyone", meaning that the whole company can Read the site. I created a sub-site, and on the sub-site I clicked "Stop Inheriting" permissions, and I want the sub-site to have no Visitors at all. The sub-site is for Members only. But when I removed "Everyone" from the Visitors group on the sub-site, that affected the parent so I had to put it back. How can I take Read permission away so that the sub-site has no Readers at all?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to create a new group, say `internal visitor`, with all the required visitors except the Everyone. In your sub-site, just remove the permission of the visitors group, then grant read permission to the new internal visitor group.